# ProtoBuf Net Dictionary Duplicate Keys Handling (Map)

Tags: c#, dictionary, duplicates, protobuf-net

I have some data which I serialized with protobuf.net. The data is a map, and contains some duplicates (which happened as my key didn't implement IEquatable)

I want to deserialize the data into a dictionary and ignore duplicates. 
There seems to be an attribute for that, i.e. `[ProtoMap(DisableMap=false)]`, which the documentation says:

> Disable "map" handling; dictionaries will use .Add(key, value) instead
>   of [key] = value. ...

Basically I want to behavior to be `[key] = value`, but apparently, the attribute is ignored.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any way to achieve the desired (and documented) behavior of ignoring duplicates?

Example code:
1. Produce data with duplicates:

```
            // ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
            //  The following part generated the bytes, which requires the key NOT to implement IEquatable
            // ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------

            var cache = new MyTestClass() { Dictionary = new Dictionary<MyTestKey, string>() };

            cache.Dictionary[new MyTestKey { Value = "X" }] = "A";
            cache.Dictionary[new MyTestKey { Value = "X" }] = "B";

            var bytes = cache.Serialize();

            var bytesStr = string.Join(",", bytes); // "10,8,10,3,10,1,88,18,1,65,10,8,10,3,10,1,88,18,1,66";

    //..



    [DataContract]
    public class MyTestKey
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        [ProtoMap(DisableMap = false)]
        public Dictionary<MyTestKey, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
    }

´´´

2. Try deserialize the data, with property IEquatable, which fails..:
```

```
[DataContract]
public class MyTestKey : IEquatable<MyTestKey>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyTestKey other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Value == other.Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((MyTestKey) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Value != null ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
//..
var bytesStr2 = "10,8,10,3,10,1,88,18,1,65,10,8,10,3,10,1,88,18,1,66";
var bytes2 = bytesStr2.Split(',').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray();
var cache = bytes2.DeserializeTo<MyTestClass>();
```

´´´

> Exception An item with the same key has already been added.

```
public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeTo<T>(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
            return default(T);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {

            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T setup)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, setup);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different things going on here; "map" mode is actually the one you *want* here - so it isn't that you're trying to *disable* map, but actually you're trying to *force it on* (it is now on by default in most common dictionary scenarios).

There are some complications:

1. the library only processes `[ProtoMap(...)]` when processing a `[ProtoMember(...)]` for a `[ProtoContract(...)]`
2. even then, it only processes `[ProtoMap(...)]` for key-types that are valid as "map" keys in the proto specification
3. you *can* turn it on manually (not via the attributes), but in v2.* it enforces the same check as #2 at runtime, which means it will fail

The manual enable from #3 **works** in v3.* (currently in alpha):

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(MyTestClass)][1].IsMap = true;
```

however, this is obviously inelegant, and *today* requires using an alpha build (we've been using it in production here at Stack Overflow for an extended period; I just need to get a release together - docs, etc).

Given that it *works*, I'm tempted to propose that we should soften #2 in v3.*, such that while the *default* behavior remains the same, it would still check for `[ProtoMap(...)]` for custom types, and enable that mode. I'm on the fence about whether to soften #1.

I'd be interested in your thoughts on these things!

But to confirm: the following works fine in v3.* and outputs `"B"` (minor explanation of the code: in protobuf, append===merge for root objects, so serializing two payloads one after the other has the same effect as serializing a dictionary with the combined content, so the two `Serialize` calls spoofs a payload with two identical keys):

```cs
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var key = new MyTestKey { Value = "X" };
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(MyTestClass)][1].IsMap = true;
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, new MyTestClass() { Dictionary = 
          new Dictionary<MyTestKey, string> { { key, "A" } } });
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, new MyTestClass() { Dictionary =
          new Dictionary<MyTestKey, string> { { key, "B" } } });


        ms.Position = 0;
        var val = Serializer.Deserialize<MyTestClass>(ms).Dictionary[key];
        Console.WriteLine(val); // B
    }
}
```

I think what I'd *like* is if, in v3.*, it worked *without* the `IsMap = true` line, with:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [ProtoMap] // explicit enable here, because not a normal map type
    public Dictionary<MyTestKey, string> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: softening up 2. would be great. I don't know the if there can be problem with the inner workings of proto with non-default key types, but from a C# perspective that should totally be possible.

Comment: I have now implemented a quick workaround by deserializing my data not into a dictionary but an array of key value tuples (which is binary compatible) and then dealing with the creation of the dictionary myself

Comment: @trykyn that (second comment) is perfectly valid, indeed